# Change id of an input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have a td in table with value i have changed this td to an input of type text when a click to a button.

And now i want to change the id of the new input with the id of the td element so i have an exception that is :

> input.id is not a function

Here my code js :

```
$("tr.forc td.TdbeforeForcage").each(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var input = $('<input class="numberforce" style="width:50%" type="text" />');
    var IdTd = $(this).attr("id");
    input.val(html);
    input.id(IdTd); // Here trying to change id of input with id of td 
    $(this).html(input);

    if (html.indexOf('&nbsp;') > -1) {
      var newValue = html.replace('&nbsp;', ' ');
      $(this).find('input.numberforce').val(newValue)
    }
});
```

Comment: All these answers and no one using best practice of `prop()`. Also note @OP that you appear to be creating a duplicate `id` (as you're taking it from the `.TdbeforeForcage` and applying the same value to the new `input`. That's invalid. In fact, I'd suggest that creating `id` attributes dynamically is a rather large code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is not a function it's a property, you would change it like so:

```
input.id = IdTd;
```

when using jQuery:

```
input.attr('id', IdTd);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

`$(input).attr("id", "newID");`

Answer (score 0):

Id is an attribute no a function. To set an id you can set it like this:

```
input.id = "id"; // input is an Element object
```

or

```
input.attr("id", "newId"); // input is a jQuery object
```

Comment: Given that `input` is a jQuery object, this won't work as you expect it to

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan for your indication. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the jquery attr method here http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

```
input.attr('id', IdTd);
```